# Is there a way that double d + 1 == d in java

Tags: java, double, precision

I'm just curious if there's a way that `d + 1 == d`. If d is a double.
Maybe someone can share some knowledge with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, certainly.

```
class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    System.out.println(1.0e52 + 1); 
  } 
}
```

prints

> 1.0E52

This will actually be true for numbers with absolute value at least 2<sup>53</sup>, because the *mantissa* of a `double` has 52 bits of precision.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. For very large (or small) doubles (or Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY), floating point precision won't be enough to store the 1 difference and `d + 1 == d` will be true.